# To clean/fill table after table in the correct order, can I simply sort all tables based on FKs?

Tags: php, mysql, database, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

This is more like a conceptual question.

I have a scheduled task with many input tables (SQLite) `table1 ... tableN` and I need to perform a series of delete/insert into MySQL, processing table after table.

```
READ SQLITE TABLE -> EMPTY MYSQL TABLE -> FILL MYSQL TABLE
```

Of course if (MySQL) `table1` has a foreign key poiting to `table2`, `table2` should be deleted and filled *before* `table1`. I manually sort the incoming tables, but it's not a good idea with 30+ table and can lead to errors.

`SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0` is **not an option**.

So problem would be sorting all MySQL table based on the number of incoming FKs (high to low), like:

```
// Doctrine DBAL example but it's easily understandable
$schema = $this->connection->getSchemaManager();

// Init chart where keys are table names, values are # of incoming FKs
$chart = array_fill_keys($schema->listTableNames(), 0);

// Build the chart
foreach ($schema->listTables() as $table) {
    foreach ($table->getForeignKeys() as $foreignKey) {
        $chart[$foreignKey->getForeignTableName()]++;
    }
}

// Sort high to low by values
arsort($chart);
```

Are there flaws in my reasoning? My question is **how to deal with self-foreign keys** (simply ignore it?) and how to **deal with circular references** (i.e. `table1 -> table2 -> table3 -> table1`).

Comment: if you have circular references, you'll **HAVE** to disable FK checks, otherwise you'll never be able to repopulate the table with the initial 'root' record.

Comment: @MarcB thank you for your comment. So I guess I need to figure out circular references and throw an exception if any (without the need to disable foreign keys).